# Ionic 3 - Get image from file.dataDirectory returns 404 not found (after normalizeURL)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m trying to show an image in my ionic view which is stored in the dataDirectory of the app. But when I set the image in the src tag, it returns a 404.

First I saved the image returned from an api into the dataDirectory and normalize the URL:

```
this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory, filename, blob, { replace: true })
.then(function(fileEntry) {
    store.photoData = normalizeURL(fileEntry.nativeURL);
    resolve();
});
```

The normalized url of the image looks like this:

http://localhost:8080/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1758E3DC-66D3-4481-8835-79C7841A540A/Library/NoCloud/1510162340797.jpg

Then I use it in my view:

```
<img *ngIf="store.photoData" [src]="store.photoData" />
```

Any ideas how to use a local resource image in a src tag? I don’t want to convert it back to base64! When I use the nativeURL with ionic file `getFile` or `readAsBinaryString` it does return a file, so it's really there!

It did add `<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*" />` to my config.xml, didn't know if that was necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was wrong with my blob. It's working now.

```
var blob: any = this.b64toBlob(contents, 'image/jpg', 512);

b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
            contentType = contentType || '';
            sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

            var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
            var byteArrays = [];

            for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
                var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

                var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                    byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
                }

                var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

                byteArrays.push(byteArray);
            }

          var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
          return blob;
}
```